# TextToSpeech App.. Calling without UI

Tags: android, text-to-speech

How to call TextToSpeech class from another class when TextToSpeech class doesn't have any UI.. In the app there is only one layout that Main Class uses.. Now my task is to make the app speak ans Interact with the User according to the Situation..

Comment: 100% duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771562/call-texttospeech-activity-without-any-ui-display

Comment: @asktomsk Sir I want to get some solution I Didn't intended to copy someOne :) .. So please .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      //decleration
  TextToSpeech talker;
Button speakButton;

//onCreate
talker = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    speakButton=new Button(this);

 // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
             speakButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
            }
        });
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }


/**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);


    }

/**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

          //  Toast.makeText(VoiceRecognition.this, matches.get(0), 5000).show();
        String device = "Bedroom";
          /*  mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         matches));     
            */
            txt.setText(""+matches.get(0));
            String host = "http://web2.anzleads.com/Android/nimboPani/web-service.php?tmote=";
            String userCommand = URLEncoder.encode(matches.get(0));
            String deviceSelected = "&org=" + device;
           res =  getServerResponse(host + userCommand + deviceSelected);
           say(""+ res);
            Toast.makeText(VoiceRecognition.this,res ,5000).show();


        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void say(String text2say){
                  talker.speak(text2say, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }


    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  say("Hello World");
    }


           public void onDestroy() {
          if (talker != null) {
                 talker.stop();
                 talker.shutdown();
              }

              super.onDestroy();
           }
 public String getServerResponse(String url)
    {
        String result = "";
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse hr ;
        HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(url);
        try
        {
            hr = hc.execute(hg);
            if(hr.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
                if (he != null)
                {
                    InputStream is = he.getContent();
                      result = convertStreamToString(is);
                      is.close();

                }
            }
        }



        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

         return result;

    }


    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream instream) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                instream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

Comment: @Sodhi Sir I'm not using the StartActivity function cause i dont want to show the Dialogue.. Can you please Elaborate whats going on in this code .. Thanks

Comment: @Sodhi Sir I want to make the app speak only some sentences that are store in DataBase.. Not from a Server .. Thanks

Comment: This code basically about voice recognition in android throgh text to speech widgets.When u run this code on clicking of start_btn a dialog will appear & whatever you speak ,it automatically convert your spoken word into text.But I think this code is not familiar with your requirement because you have a db in which sentences are stored, you may use mp3 files of particular sentences with media player object in android & that solution will definately work because I also have such a circumstance in past app where i use mp3 files of particular words & senetences.....

Comment: Sir how do i use mp3 files ? Can this task be achieve by TextToSpeech built in adnroid :|

Comment: No the above task can't be acheive using TextToSpeech inbuilt functionality. You have to make the mp3 files of the sentences & store these file in raw which you will be create under res folder & use MediaPlayer inbuilt class in android playing these mp3 files..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a UI or an Activity to use TextToSpeech.